# Image not saving SQLite Database with C# Desktop Application

Tags: c#, sqlite, desktop-application

I am trying to Save image from picture box to Sqlite & retrieve Image on picturebox from SqliteDB with C#.
what it is saving in Database you can see here in the picture in database data type for image is blob

[image]

When i am trying to retrieve and show image in picture box it is showing following error.
[image]

Here is the Code:

```
    using Finisar.SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SQLiteDb
{
    public partial class ImageForm : Form
    {
        public ImageForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //To convert immage into bytes
            Image img = pictureBox1.Image;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] dataByte = ms.ToArray();


           // Saving into database. . 
            sqlite_conn.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd_Insert = new SQLiteCommand("Insert into ForImage(ID,FileImage) values ('"+12+"','" + dataByte + "')", sqlite_conn);
            cmd_Insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        // To Show/load Image in Picturebox 1.
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sqlite_conn.Open();

            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("Select FileImage from ForImage where ID=12", sqlite_conn);
            byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            MemoryStream mm = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
            Image img = Image.FromStream(mm);
            pictureBox2.Image = img;

        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me what is the problem in the code.

Comment: The fact that the `DataGridView` (or whatever control that is) doesn't display an image doesn't mean that the bytes in the table are wrong.

Comment: What you save to the db is `byte[] dataByte` so, `System.Byte[]` is correct.  What did you expect to see for a BLOB column?

Comment: in database it should show array of bytes not System.Byte[]. @Plutonix

Comment: `System.Byte[]` ***is*** an array ( `[]` ) of `Byte` which is defined in the `System` namespace.

Comment: ok but when I am trying to retrive this byte aray from database converting it into image and showing it in Picturebox it is giving error why? @Plutonix

Comment: That sounds like a completely different question that what you have posted.  There is nothing shown for what you are trying and "giving error" is not in the least helpful.  You would do the reverse of saving it.

Comment: @Plutonix I try to more clarify my problem by editing the question please read it again hope you can understand it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Solution and Working Code for the above mention problem:

```
using Finisar.SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SQLiteDb
{
    public partial class Final_Form : Form
    {
        public Final_Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
        Image image;
        private void Upload_image_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                image = pictureBox1.Image;
            }
        }

        private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] imagesBytes = Image2Byte(pictureBox1.Image);
            SaveImage(imagesBytes);
        }

        private void Show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadImageFromDb();
        }
        //Retrive Image Code. . 

        private void LoadImageFromDb()
        {
            con.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("Select FileImage from ForImage where ID='86';", con);
            byte[] arrayFromDb = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            con.Close();
            pictureBox2.Image = ByteToImage(arrayFromDb);
        }
        private Image ByteToImage(byte[] toConvert)
        {
            MemoryStream toImage = new MemoryStream(toConvert);
            Image imageFromBytes = Image.FromStream(toImage);
            return imageFromBytes;
        }
        //Picture Save Methods Define Here. . 
        #region
        private void SaveImage(byte[] imageBytes2Save)
        {
            string Query_ = "INSERT INTO ForImage (ID,FileImage) VALUES (86,@0);";
            SQLiteParameter PicParam = new SQLiteParameter("@0", DbType.Binary);
            PicParam.Value = imageBytes2Save;

            con.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(Query_,con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(PicParam);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }

        private byte[] Image2Byte(Image imageToconvert)
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            imageToconvert.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] bytesOfImage = memoryStream.ToArray();
            return bytesOfImage;
        }

        #endregion




    }
}
```

// Here is the output

[image]

- Upload a picture to Image box
- Save picture to Database(SQLITE)
- Retrieve from database to show in Picturebox

**How I solved the Problem?**
**Ans :** By putting Parameter in Query for saving Image in Database.